# Parse table of objects in ASP.NET controller

Tags: asp.net

I work with ASP.NET and I send a request to the server with ajax the request have this data:

```
{
    __RequestVerificationToken: token,
    Exercice: exercice,
    Phase: selectedPhase,
    DateMin: dateMin,
    DateFin: dateMax,
    Nb_Jours: days,
    MDN_Role_Program: tableData
},
```

but the `MDN_Role_Program` count was 48 and the attributes was null someone tell me why?

This is the class:

```
public partial class MDN_RoleDateSaisi
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MDN_RoleDateSaisi()
    {
        this.MDN_Role_Program = new HashSet<MDN_Role_Program>();
    }

    public string Role { get; set; }
    public int Exercice { get; set; }
    public int Phase { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateMin { get; set; }
    public double Nb_Jours { get; set; }
    public short Statut { get; set; }
    public string RoleCaption { get; set; }
    public string Phase_Caption { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateFin { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MDN_Role_Program> MDN_Role_Program { get; set; }
}
```

This is the action method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(MDN_RoleDateSaisi model)
{
```